# Al rellenar un diccionario python en for me repite el ultimo valor en los demas items

Tags: python, array, python-2.x, diccionarios

Tengo un diccionario que quiero rellenar con dos listas, una que tiene las key y otra que tiene los valores, cuando itero con el for para guardar cada item los va sacando en orden y los guarda, pero al momento de imprimir el diccionario veo que el ultimo valor esta repetido en todos los items

```
arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arreglo_2 = ['aguilas', 'tigres', 'leones', 'estrellas', 'gigantes', 'toros', ]
EQUIPOS_DICT = {}

for a in arreglo:
    for a2 in arreglo_2:
        print 'Se guardara %s' % (a2)
        EQUIPOS_DICT[str(a)] = a2

EQUIPOS = EQUIPOS_DICT.items()

print EQUIPOS

SALIDA> 
[('1', 'toros'), ('3', 'toros'), ('2', 'toros'), ('5', 'toros'), ('4', 'toros'), ('6', 'toros')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es este código:

```
for a in arreglo:
    for a2 in arreglo_2:
```

Por cada clave recorres cada vez todos los valores, entonces cada vez que haces: `EQUIPOS_DICT[str(a)] = a2` estas actualizando el valor de la clave `str(a)`, por lo que al final te quedas siempre con el último valor.

La solución es bien sencilla, puede hacer esto:

```
EQUIPOS = dict(zip(arreglo, arreglo_2))
print(EQUIPOS)
```

Y la salida que obtendrías:

```
[('1', 'aguilas'), ('3', 'leones'), ('2', 'tigres'), ('5', 'gigantes'), ('4', 'estrellas'), ('6', 'toros')]
```

Lo que hacemos es usar [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) que "mapea" cada valor de una lista con la de la otra, generando "tuplas", por ejemplo: `(1, 'aguilas'), (2, 'tigres)...`, y con `dict` construimos el diccionario a partir de estas tuplas. Una condición, es que ambas listas tengan la misma cantidad de valores, eventualmente podríamos mapear una lista de claves con una lista menor de valores pero deberíamos usar [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Si eventualmente quieres usar la forma básica, mediante un ciclo `for`, la forma correcta sería esta:

```
i = 0
for a in arreglo:
  EQUIPOS_DICT[str(a)] = arreglo_2[i]
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono